# Android Firebase Auth Token Expired

Tags: android, firebase-authentication

I use FirebaseAuth on Android to log my users into the app.
Everything works perfectly with `'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:10.2.6'`

The second that I update to anything higher than `10.2.6` I start to see this:
`E/Volley: [13546] BasicNetwork.performRequest: Unexpected response code 400 for https://securetoken.googleapis.com/v1/token?alt=proto&key=myKeyWasHere`
`I/AuthChimeraService: Error description received from server: TOKEN_EXPIRED`

I noticed in the release notes there were a lot of changes to Auth starting on version `11.0.0` https://firebase.google.com/support/release-notes/android#20171030

Am I missing something here? Am I supposed to refresh the token now?

Comment: Was the user deleted, disabled or did you update that user's email or password?

Comment: No. I literally just change the version number and it stops working. Then I change your back and it works again.